# How to count frequency of occurrences in the last 7 days when data has date/time

Tags: powerbi, dax, frequency

Here is the sample dataset, having 2 columns, Data, and Name
[image]

The problem is to create a measure that is going to count the number of name occurrences having a count greater than 2

**Step 1** is to find the Names that show up at least once a day without a timestamp

[image]

**Step 2** is to find names that have occurrences of more than 2 from the output got of Step 1:

[image]

**Step 3:** is to get the distinct count of names from Step 2:

**Expected Output =  2**

Not sure how to do this in DAX.

**Note: I m looking for a measure that gives the Output = 2 and not the steps, the steps are for understanding purposes/ or to provide clarity**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing for updated list:

[image]

I basically did this:

```
Measure = 
var base = 
SUMMARIZE(data,Data[Name],"Count",count(Data[Date]))
return calculate( countrows(filter(base,[Count] >2)))
```

which gives the output: Sam(8), Tim(3), Ahmed(3), Jake(4), Oscar(3)

[image]

Then to get the count of frequent names in the last 7 days I use the below measure:

```
Measure 2 = 
var last_7 = now() - 7
return calculate( [Measure], filter(Data, Data[Date] >= last_7))
```

The result is shown below: Checks for count more than 2 times in the last 7 days (that is starting 5/5/2023), The result is 2, because the counts>2 are Sam(5) and Oscar(3).

[image]

Comment: `calculate( Measure, filter(data, data'Date' >= last_7))` This will consider dates more than 7 days also

Comment: Hi Ashok, I have updated my answer to provide Images and explanations.

Comment: last_7 is basically, now() -7. meaning today - 7 days

Answer (score 1):

First write a measure to count the names

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNT(Data[Name]), FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(data, Data[Name]), Data[Date] <= DATEVALUE("2023-05-07")))
```

Then use that measure to count names more than 2

```
Measure 2 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Data[Name]), FILTER(data, [Measure] > 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you either split your date and time column into separate columns or create them in your fact table, then this is trivial using FILTER and COUNTROWS() and maybe RELATEDTABLE().

Comment: I solved it using the code I posted below.